# MongoDB & Multer - How do I convert a buffer binary to an image?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer

I'm trying to make a simple website where I can upload an image to MongoDB and return it. All was going well until I got to the returning the image portion.

Right now, I can upload an image to the website using multer, when I upload the image do the database, it gets converted into binary data. Could anyone please show me how I would be able to convert the binary data to an image? that'll greatly appreciated!!

**Schema & Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const fileStorageOneSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    img: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
})

const fileStorageOne = mongoose.model("fileStorageOne", fileStorageOneSchema);
module.exports = fileStorageOne
```

**Multer Storage**

```
const fileStorageOne = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads/fileOne/',
    filename: (req,file,cb)=> {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + ' - ' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})
```

**Express Upload to MongoDB**

```
app.post('/upload_filestorageone', (req,res)=> {
    uploadFileStorageOne(req, res, (err)=> {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/')
        } else {
            const newImage = new fileStorageOneModel({
                img: {
                    data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/fileOne/' + req.file.filename)),
                    contentType: 'image/png'
                }
            })
            newImage.save((err)=> {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect('/')
                } else {
                    console.log('Successfully uploaded a photo!');
                    res.redirect('/filestorageone')
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**Express Return the Image**

```
app.get('/filestorageone/:id', (req,res)=> {
    fileStorageOneModel.findOne({}, (err,data)=> {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            const image = new Buffer(data.img.data).toString('base64')
            return res.json(image)
        }
    })
})
```

**EJS Upload**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <%- include('./partials/header') %>
        </header>
        <%- include('./partials/version') %>

        <div class="submit-image-style">
            <form action="upload_filestorageone" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="fileStorageOneImages">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="output-style">
                <% image.forEach((image)=> { %>
                    <a href="/filestorageone/<%= image._id %>"><%= image._id %></a>
                <% }) %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the messy code, still pretty new to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending the image with the `.json()` method, you'll want to set the appropriate content type so that the browser knows that it's an image, then just `.send()` the buffer:

```
app.get("/filestorageone/:id", (req, res) => {
  fileStorageOneModel.findOne({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return res.type(data.img.contentType).send(data.img.data);
    }
  });
});
```

Here I'm using [`.type()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.type) which can also look up the correct mime type from a file extension, but you could just as well use `.header('Content-Type', data.img.contentType)`.

I've also left out the `new Buffer()` call since it's already a `Buffer`.

As a side-note, assuming you're using `multer` and `DiskStorage`, you don't need to construct the path with `path.join()` and `req.file.filename`, as the full path can be found from `req.file.path`. You can also use `req.file.mimetype` so that you get the correct content type for also non-PNG images.